# Energia IDE arduino.h not found during compilation

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, installation, ide, microcontroller

I am starting my first project with an ArduCam cc3200 board. In the manual I read that I have to use the Energia IDE for this. When I installed Energia IDE and tried to compile an example sketch, I got the error message: "sketch\Sweep.ino.cpp:1:21: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory". Other example sketches give the same error. The Arduino.h file is available in the \Documents\energia-1.6.10E18\hardware\energia\msp430\cores\msp430 folder, but for some reason energia cannot find it. 
Does anyone has an idea why energia cannot find this file and how I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some times it happens i don't know the reason but you can try to put that folder on other location and than choose that path i have face same issue in past,

Comment: @AjayPandya thanks for your response, I tried to put it in another location but I did not change any path. Which path should I change/ choose. Do I have to set that somewhere in the IDE, or on my pc?